# UFT- Debug without Microsoft script debugger

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

We are using UFT-version 12.0, As microsoft script debugger is depriciated , we are not able to install it, we work in client environment, so cannot download it from external sources. Please suggest any alternatives to debug the script in QTP.

Comment: https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/UFT-Practitioners-Forum/Microsoft-Script-Debugger-Not-Installing-I-get-the-following/td-p/221019

Comment: @Barney, you should add this as an answer